# TCP_MSE_HIT/200 meaning in squid access.log

Tags: squid

what is the meaning of TCP_MSE_HIT/200? I searched for it in squid FAQ ([here](http://proxy.ccu.edu.tw/squidfaq/FAQ.pdf))
and squid wiki ([here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#Squid_result_codes)) but I didn't find anything. actually the main problem is with MSE meaning!

Comment: And under what circumstances do you generate that entry ? I suspect it may be a typo somewhere in the code but cant check till you confirm what version of squid and build from where.

Comment: I don't know the version of squid because I just have a text file of its log.

Comment: Can you share an extract from the log ?

Answer (score 0):

sapos to be TCP_MEM_HIT/200

`-MEM` = Additional tag indicating the response object came from memory cache, avoiding disk accesses. Only seen on HIT responses.

`-200` = Successful Transaction is OK

read more on the [squid-cache wiki](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log)